# Protect a Cordova/ionic application against decompiling

Tags: cordova, decompiling

how can a developer protect his ionic/cordova application against decompiling?

I've read some articles about decompiling mobile applications and it seems to be easy after the device is rooted/jailbroken so I'm wondering how a developer can protect his app against this.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You can't, you can uglify and some other things, but not avoid decompiling

Comment: What about to bring a launcher which will download the right .js files after a user did enter a correct login. Is it possible to load content after installation?

Comment: once the user downloads the .js, he can access them on the device

Comment: so it means I could bring a launcher version to the app store which will download the full app after a correct login? How would the launcher look like?

Comment: what I mean is, if the app downloads the .js, the user/hacker can get it, so what's the point of doing that?

Comment: the hacker have to know the right credentials to download the necessary .js files. Without the right credentials the hacker only have the launcher version of the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91105/discussion-between-kingalione-and-jcesarmobile).